# Keep LibreOffice up-to-date

Tags: update, automation

we have a terminalserver where we want to work with LibreOffice. The problem is that I don't exactly know how I can keep it automatically up-to-date. Is there like an update.exe I could run on server startup? I know there is a (still buggy?) autoupdater build in but as our users don't have administraticve rights they can't do the update themself.

Thank you!

Comment: Then run the updater as an administrative user.

Comment: but is there an updater or do I have to download the newest installer each version?